# How can I move the position of an image that's inline with some text?

Tags: css, image, list, position

I have the following:

```
<li><a class='disabled' ><img src='../../Content/Icons/home.png' />Home</a></li>
```

My li height is 25px and my img is 16x16. What I would like to do is to make the image line up with the text and also have a small space between the image and text. I tried the following:

```
img { padding-top: 6px; margin-right: 4px; }
```

The image moves down but the text moves down as well.

Is there a way I could just add padding or margin to the image without the text moving?

Please note that I already use set (and change) the background color so I need to use the img tag.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use:

```
img {
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px
}
```

That will move only the `img` down `6px` from where it would have been.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
html:

```
<li class="menu"><a class='disabled' >Home</a></li>
```

css:

```
li.menu { 
  background-image: url(../../Content/Icons/home.png) left 6px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 4px;
 }
```

Comment: I already use the background image to set the color. I wish I could use this but I can't. That's why I chose to use img. Sorry for not putting this in the post. I updated my question now.

Comment: @Marie and what problem to use both color & image?

Comment: Oh I though it was either one or the other?

Answer (score -1):

You can also give the

or the

```
a{
  float:left;
}
```

(wiil not take into account the pesky 6px from the image - thirtydot mentioned)